# After updating Selenium to ver 4.9, Internet Explorer mode not working on Edge browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The below code was working fine, but I don't know why it's not working now. I updated Selenium to ver 4.9.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

ie_options = webdriver.IeOptions()
ie_options.attach_to_edge_chrome = True
ie_options.edge_executable_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
driver = webdriver.Ie(options=ie_options)
ie_options.add_additional_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
ie_options.add_additional_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

username1 = "admin"
password1 = "admin123"
driver.maximize_window()

links = ["http://web1.com", "http://web2.com", "http://web3.com"]
count = 1
for link in links:
     time.sleep(1)
     driver.get(link)
     windows_before = driver.current_window_handle
     elem1 = driver.find_element("id", "username").send_keys(username1)
     elem2 = driver.find_element("id", "password").send_keys(password1)
     time.sleep(1)

    if count == 1:
        driver.execute_script('document.title = "web1"')
    elif count == 2:
        driver.execute_script('document.title = "web2"')
    else:
        driver.execute_script('document.title = "web3"')
    if count == 3:
      break
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    new_window = driver.window_handles[count]
    count += 1
    driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
```

Error

```
Unable to obtain driver using Selenium Manager: internet explorer is not a valid browser.  Choose one of: ['chrome', 'firefox', 'edge', 'MicrosoftEdge', 'ie']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test66.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Ie(options=ie_options)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.iedriver.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.iedriver, options)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 43, in get_path
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
    path = shutil.which(service.path) or SeleniumManager().driver_location(options)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 84, in driver_location
    raise SeleniumManagerException(
selenium.common.exceptions.SeleniumManagerException: Message: internet explorer is not a valid browser.  Choose one of: ['chrome', 'firefox', 'edge', 'MicrosoftEdge', 'ie']

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you what the problem is.

Comment: Updated from what version? Did you read any release notes on breaking changes?

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium 4.6+, `DriverManager` now takes care of downloading, installing, and setting up the specified driver for you. You need to update your options to work with new Edge.

A simple example would be

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.IeOptions()
options.ignore_zoom_level = True
options.attach_to_edge_chrome = True
driver = webdriver.Ie(options=options)
```

See [this page](https://titusfortner.com/2022/09/28/edge-ie-mode.html) for more info.

Comment: this is not working with me the below link mention my problem 

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11928